# Managing large numbers of content items in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

We are reviewing Orchard CMS as a possible CMS for a new project. The site we need to create will probably have several hundred pages and will have a page hierarchy several levels deep. The flat listing of all content items in the dashboard without any kind of tree structure or other way to allow easy navigation and management of this amount of content seems like it could present a serious issue.

I see that it has the concept of projections and queries, and the content items can be filtered by projection, but is this the only way to help a content editor navigate their content and manage position in a hierarchy?

Are there any modules or strategies to help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is taxonomy as well (Contrib.Taxonomies), and you can enable admin search so that your content items are easier to find from the content screen. That is pluggable as well, and you could easily extend those screens to set-up your own filters and navigation.